# How can i set axis unit label?

Tags: android, android-graphview

I'm using android graphview 3.1.1. I am trying to set an axis label, a label identifying what the axis is.

The only thing I've found close to this in Android GraphView is setting individual tick-mark labels as with`graphView.setHorizontalLabels(horlabels)`. Is it possible to set the entire label?

Example here, the axis labels are Month and Weight in Kg.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no build-in feature for that, but you can achieve this by nesting the GraphView-View in layouts with TextViews

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar problem, so I set a by -90° rotated TextView beside my LinearLayout where i draw the graph.

```
<TextView
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/test"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:gravity="center"
android:rotation="-90"
android:textSize="12dp"
android:text="°C"/>
```

The problem with this method: The width of my rotated TextView stays the same like if's not rotated. So there is a huge amount of space to the left and right if you use a long text. If you shorten the `layout_widht` there is a line break.

For short text it looks nice: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWMk8.jpg

Answer (score 1):

There are no ways provided to set the entire label. You may have to do this with TextViews.